# macOS Sierra will only mirror displays when connected with Air Display 3

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

I am using macOS Sierra and using an iPad Pro as a second monitor using Air Display 3.

The display will only mirror, I can not get it to act as a second screen.

When I use "System Preferences -> Displays" I get an error: "Could not load Displays preference pane.".

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

> Press Command-F1 to toggle to multiple displays.

This is the long answer that I got from the company that makes air display:

> Unfortunately you're running into a known bug in Sierra's Displays
>   preference pane. We believe this bug affects all virtual displays, not
>   just Air Display. We've reported the bug to Apple and hope have been
>   hoping that they are able to fix it in a near-term macOS software
>   update. A few days ago, I got an email saying that the bug I reported
>   has been closed. There's no way to tell whether that means it has been
>   closed with a disposition of "Fixed" or "Will Not Fix" or "Not a Bug."
>   But we're hopeful that it's going to be fixed in macOS 10.12.3, which
>   is in beta now.
>
> Meanwhile, while you can't rearrange the monitor placements, you can
>   toggle between Mirroring and Screen Extension modes by pressing
>   Command-F1. (Depending on your Keyboard settings, you may have to hold
>   down the Fn key at the same time.)
>
> Apple is aware of this issue with bug report: <rdar://28888038>.

Answer (score 0):

I quit the AirDisplay host.

Then I loaded the “Displays” preference pane.

Then I turned off “show mirroring options in the menu bar when available.”

Then I relaunched the AirDisplay host and connected to my iPad Pro.

Then the display“Displays”preference pane loaded properly (and I was able to change the arrangement of my displays)